# How do I go about fixing my read file method?

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, try-catch

> Read File:
>
> This method has a single parameter, which is the name of the file.
>   The purpose of this method is to read the contents of the file into an array.
>   You must use a try/catch block and a scanner object.
>   The first line of the file has an integer that specifies the number of lines.
>   Read this value into the variable numberLines.
>   Call nextLine again to discard the rest of the line!
>   Allocate the fileContents array to have numberLineThe elements.
>   Write a for loop that reads the specified number of lines into fileContents.
>   The catch exception code should do nothing or report an error.

This is my current code. What am I doing wrong?

```
 public void readFile(String filename) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

            Scanner read = new Scanner(new File(filename));
            int[] fileContents = {numberLines};
            numberLines = read.nextInt();
            read.nextLine();

            for(int i = 0; i < numberLines; i ++){

                fileContents[i] = read.nextInt();

                read.close();
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void readFile(String filename) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

            Scanner read = new Scanner(new File(filename));
            //int[] fileContents = {numberLines}; //fileContents has one element
            numberLines = read.nextInt();
            //you can read numberLines first and then create fileContents array as you wish
            int[] fileContents = new int[numberLines];
            //if each line only contains a number, you can read line to String and convert it to int
            //read.nextLine();

            for(int i = 0; i < numberLines; i ++){
                String nextLine = read.nextLine();
                //fileContents[i] = read.nextInt();
                fileContents[i] = Integer.parseInt(nextLine);
                //read.close();
            }
            //close read after all lines were read
            read.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Some exceptions maybe thrown:

`NoSuchElementException` -- if no line was found

`IllegalStateException` -- if this scanner is closed

Comment: It doesn't say. When I submit the assignment, that portion of it just says, "cannot invoke method: readFile"